# How do you escape special characters in the CONTAINS predicate of a FullTextSqlQuery in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: fulltextsqlquery, containspredicate

I am using the CONTAINS predicate in a full text SQL query in SP2010 Standard.  Yes, I'd rather do a Keyword Query, but it doesn't appear to be able to handle what I need.

I have learned things like changing a space to a "+" in all quoted queries, changing a space between words to " OR ", etc.

I have also found that the following characters seem to mess up a query if put in CONTAINS:

```
~!()&[]|',
```

My current fix is to simply remove these from the query.  This is probably OK for all but the single quote.  If a user wants to find "can't" or "O'Reilly" they really need to be able to.  I must use a CONTAINS because I have to limit this to certain fields (metadata properties).

I have tried escaping it with \', \', \\', '', &#27;, and a few others I can't remember but none have worked for me.

Surprisingly the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms513993.aspx) on this doesn't mention escaping any characters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms516214.aspx) part of the documentation mentions that escaping is done with '' but also claims it's not needed for CONTAINS ?!?

> When performing queries with contractions and using the FREETEXT
>   predicate, you must escape the quotation mark in the contraction; you
>   do not have to do this when using the CONTAINS predicate.
>
> For example, the following syntax fails:
>
> …WHERE FREETEXT(*,'"We'll always have Paris"')
>
> The correct syntax includes two single quotation marks.
>
> The following syntax succeeds:
>
> …WHERE FREETEXT(*,'"We''ll always have Paris"')

Comment: I guess the documentation and I will have to agree to disagree :-S.